# Entity with properties mapped on blob/text sql field

Tags: drupal-8

I Have an entity (taht extends Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase). I try to map some property of this entity on blob or text mysql field.

In the documentation, I don't see wichh value I have to put in BaseFieldDefinition::create(VALUE ???).

Maybe it's not possible ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Core field types:**
boolean
changed
comment
created
datetime
decimal
email
entity_reference
file
float
image
integer
language
link
list_float
list_integer
list_string
map
password
path
string
string_long
telephone
text
text_long
text_with_summary
timestamp
uri
uuid

Documented [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/fieldtypes-fieldwidgets-and-fieldformatters)